# searchBox Google Maps with pagination

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, pagination

So what I am trying to do is implement Google Maps with a search box. Currently, the search box retrieves 20 of the top places based on the search result.

What I noticed is there is no pagination with this. Such as if I type in “pizza”, it will give me the top 20 results in the current location bounds. But when I use the `google.maps.places.PlacesService(map)` textSearch function to obtain a list of pizza searches, I get more than 20 results with pagination.

Is there a way to get pagination on your searchBox or use the textSearch function to provide pagination after you used searchBox?

What I have here is a snippet:

```js
var canvas = element.find('div')[0];
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    minZoom: 2,
};
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox('pizza');
var placeService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', locationChange);

function locationChange() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
    //Determine if there are additional places not provided by searchbox. Using text 
    var request = {
        query: input.value,
    };
    var textSearchPlaces = placeService.textSearch(request, callback);
    function callback(results, status, pagination) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            var hi = places;
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var place = results[i];
            }
        }
    }
    if (places.length === 0) {
        return;
    }
};
```

As you can see this is not the most ideal solution to looking using a pagination as I would have to filter through the textSearchPlaces to see if those places are not duplicates of the searchBox results.

I also thought about just removing the searchBox and just going with the textSearch function but I realized I wouldn’t have the autoComplete function that provides suggestions that searchBox provides.

Comment: Completely ignore the places returned by the searchbox and run only a textSearch based on the value of the `<input>`

Comment: Hmmm thats an interesting way of doing it Lol.

Answer (score -2):

Most likely you are getting  [`OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_responses).

`if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {`

Try queuing the  [details requests](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#TextSearchRequests) for after you have all the list completed, adding the same timeout logic to check for `google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` on this line.

```
if (pagination.hasNextPage) {
//add all places to the list
setTimeout('pagination.nextPage()',2000);
}  else {
createMarkers(placesList);
}
```

You should use `google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` when using Places.